# How to switch data type on run time

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

In the library I am using it has functions with different signatures as follows

```
void Func( int* ptr);
void Func( float* ptr);
void Func( double* ptr);
```

My function needs to decide which function to call depending on an input flag iSwitch as follows:

```
void test( int iSwitch, void* ptr1)
{
    switch (iSwitch)
    {
        case 0:
              Func( (int*) ptr1);
              break;
        case 1:
              Func((float*) ptr1);
              break;
        case 3:
              Func((double*) ptr1);
              break;
    }
}
```

It should be OK. However I do not want to put Func inside the switch block. I want to be able to somehow switch type of pointer first in the switch block and then have only 1 Func after that in which ptr1 is dynamically casted to the corresponding type.

Specifically, I want something as follows:

```
void test( int iSwitch, void* ptr1)
{
   switch( iSwitch)
   {
   // I want to be able to somehow switch type of pointer (say   DummyDataType) here depending iSwitch 

    }
    Func(( DummyDataType) ptr1);

 }
```

Can you please advice how I can do this?

Thank you !

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like what templates are for. Or pointer arrays.

Comment: `boost::variant` might help you.

Comment: The called overload must be selected at compile time (therefore you need those three calls in the switch).

Answer (score 1):

You can't store a type in a variable, and then use it in a cast later, if that's what you're asking.  The compiler needs to know the type of a cast at compile time, otherwise it can't correctly generate the code in order to do it.  Additionally the compiler needs to know the type of an argument to a function at compile time.  Otherwise, it won't know which version of the function to dispatch.  I think your solution is as good as it's going to get, although if you're using a flag to switch on the type of a variable, you might want to take a look at your design.  Maybe give us some more context and we can offer some better solutions.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks